# No cache hit on repeated queries using quarkus panache finder

Tags: hibernate, caching, quarkus

I try to see, that repeating the same query by panache finder in quarkus test, makes under the hood use of hibernate cache.
That's why I check sessionFactory.getStatistics().getQueryCacheHitCount() which however also returns 0 after second same query, where I expected 1 cache hit.

```
        FilePart f1 = FilePart.find("id=1").firstResult();
        
        Statistics stats = sessionFactory.getStatistics();
        assertEquals(1, stats.getQueryExecutionCount());
        assertEquals(0, stats.getQueryCacheHitCount());

        FilePart f2 = FilePart.find("id=1").firstResult();
        assertSame(f2, f1); //identical object from first query is returned

        stats = sessionFactory.getStatistics();
        assertEquals(1, stats.getQueryExecutionCount()); //2
        assertEquals(1, stats.getQueryCacheHitCount());  //0, there should be a cache hit for identical query
```

Complete reproducer here: https://github.com/syr/quarkus-resteasy-postgres/blob/hibernate-cache-tests/src/test/java/org/acme/DownloadSyncResourceTest.java

UPDATE:

also with hint there is no cache hit

```
FilePart.find("id=1").withHint("javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode", CacheRetrieveMode.USE).firstResult()
```